# Set focus to text after closing modal form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an application using VB NET and trying to figure out how to achieve what i wanted but seems i stuck there.

I have `Form1` with `Button1` and `Textbox1`, when we clicked on `Button1`, it will open `Form2` modally `Form2.ShowDialog()`. Now after `Form2` closed, i would like to set `Textbox1` in `Form1`.

So far what i have tried is to put `Form1.Textbox1.Select()` method in `Form2` both in `FormClosed` and `FormClosing` event, but it does not worked. And then tried to put `Me.Textbox1.Select` method in `Form1` `Activated` event does not worked as well.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: TextBox1. Focus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is how you call it in `Button1`:

```
Form2.ShowDialog()
```

You can simply put:

`TextBox1.Focus()` after `Form2.ShowDialog()` so that when `Form2` was closed, `TextBox1` will be focused on `Form1`.

As simple as this:

```
Form2.ShowDialog()
TextBox1.Focus()
```

When you call a `ShowDialog()`, it will not proceed to the next code until that form was closed.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy coding.